# Why is the group_by method changing my object's attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by

I am trying to display note objects grouped by when they were created.  I can display them correctly without the group by, but it seems like I am losing the reference to the object attributes when I try to group.  This is the error I am getting:

```
undefined method `title' for #<Array:0x0000000aeb52d0>
```

On this line:

```
<%= link_to note.title, {:action => 'show', :id => note.id} -%>
```

Here is the relevant part of the view:

```
<ul id = "notes">
    <% @notes.group_by(&:created_at).each do |note| %>
    <li>
        <%= link_to note.title, {:action => 'show', :id => note.id} -%>
        <% if note.category == 0%>
            <%= label_tag 'category', 'Note' %>
        <% else %>
            <%= label_tag 'category', 'Goal' %>
            <%= note.dueDate %>
        <% end %>
    </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Here is the migration:

```
class Notes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :notes do |t|
        t.string :title, limit: 40, null: false
        t.boolean :category, default: false, null: false
        t.string :description, limit: 1000
        t.string :dueDate
        t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Just small comments to the code. Ruby on Rails has several conventions related to naming of model classes and columns. The model classes should be named in singular form (for example Note), but table names should be in plural form (notes). And column names should be written in snake_case, for instance due_date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enumerable#group_by` method returns hash, where key is the attribute (`created_at`) you're grouping by and value is an array of objects with the same value of the attribute.

```
Notes.all.group_by(&:created_at)
=> {Sat, 22 Jul 2017 15:54:24 UTC +00:00=>[#<Notes id:1 ... >]}
```

So, if you're grouping notes for some reason, you might need to display the notes grouped. For example:

```
<div id = "notes">
  <% @notes.group_by(&:created_at).each do |created_at, notes| %>
    <div> <%= created_at %> </div>
    <ul class="grouped-notes">
      <% notes.each do |note| %>
        <li>
            <%= link_to note.title, {:action => 'show', :id => note.id} -%>
            <% if note.category == 0%>
                <%= label_tag 'category', 'Note' %>
            <% else %>
                <%= label_tag 'category', 'Goal' %>
                <%= note.dueDate %>
            <% end %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```